# reading string input for calculator in C

Tags: c, calculator

Basically I'm trying to get a string from the user in the form: 3 + 2 , as a single string, check the components of the string individually and do the calculation. I already have the calculator program working with command line input, but i need to get and read string input from the user if they don't use command line

This is what i have so far. Please hellppp :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int num1, num2;
float ans;
char operator;
int i = 0, j = 0;
char s[100] = " ";
char s1[100], s2[100];




if (argc==4) {
sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &num1);
sscanf(argv[2], "%c", &operator);
sscanf(argv[3], "%d", &num2);

switch (operator) {
  case '+': ans = num1+num2;
    printf("%d %c %d = %.2f\n", num1, operator, num2, ans);
        break;
  case '-': ans = num1-num2;
    printf("%d %c %d = %.2f\n", num1, operator, num2, ans);
        break;
  case 'x':
  case 'X': ans = num1*num2;
        printf("%d %c %d = %.2f\n", num1, operator, num2, ans);
            break;
  case '^': ans = pow(num1, num2);
            printf("%d %c %d = %.2f\n", num1, operator, num2, ans);
            break;

  case '/': if (num2 == 0) {
      printf("Error! Division by Zero!\n");
    }
    else {
      ans = num1/num2;
      printf("%d %c %d = %.2f\n", num1, operator, num2, ans);
    }           
        break;
  default: printf("%c is not a valid operator!\n", operator);
  }}
 else
 if (argc==3) {
sscanf(argv[1], "%c", &operator);
sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &num1);

switch (operator) {
  case 'n':
  case 'N': ans = -num1;
        printf("-(%d) = %.2f\n", num1, ans);
        break;
  case 'a':
  case 'A': ans = fabs(num1);
        printf("|%d| = %.2f\n", num1, ans);
    break;


  case 's':
  case 'S': if (num1 < 0) {
      printf("Can't find square root of negative number\n");
    }
    else {
      ans = sqrt(num1);
      printf("Sqrt(%d) = %.2f\n", num1, ans);
    }
        break;
  default: printf("%c is not a valid operator!\n", operator);
} }

else if ((argc!=3) || (argc!=4)) {

printf("Enter the string you want to calculate: ");
gets(s);




while (s[i] != '\0') {

s[i] = argv[1];

i++;

} 

 while 
(s[i] != '\0') {

s[i] = argv[2];

i++;

}
 while 
 (s[i] != '\0') {

 s[i] = argv[3];

 i++;

 }}

}
else 
printf("Input Error!!!\n");
}
```

Comment: First, you should be using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to get a line of input from the user. Secondly, the whole string is terminated by `'\0'`, not each "word" in the string. Thirdly look up the [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function to split up a string on a delimiter. Point four, you try to assign a string (e.g. `argv[1]`) to a character (`s[i]`). And lastly, you can actually use `sscanf` on the string you read directly, no need to split it up.

Comment: `but i need to get and read string input from the user if they don't use command line` - so what about this is specifically your problem?

Comment: using the appropriate string functions and making it work with the calculator

Answer (score 2):

First of, you should be using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read the input, as `gets` is vulnerable to buffer overflows:

```
fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
```

Then you can simply use `sscanf` to get the data you need:

```
sscanf(s, "%d %c %d", &num1, &operator, &num2);
```